# Please merge my two accounts

Tags: support, status-completed, duplicate-accounts

It seems I have two accounts. Request, please merge my accounts.

I would prefer my OpenID account credentials to login. So kindly allow me to keep the latest one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your accounts have been merged.

Comment: Thanks for your help in merging the accounts.

Comment: @Arindom: can you find the [v] accept button here?

Comment: @Lekensteyn: I think you mean the right accept icon (it doesn't look like a [v]. As I understand the [v] icon is for vote up or down. For this one I have already accepted this answer.

Comment: @Arindom: there are no brackets around the vote buttons. Does `(v)` better describe the vote button?